# Facebook app: posting to user's wall message field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, posting

I have a Facebook app, where users upload their photos and these are then shared on their wall. However, Facebook wants them to be able to compose the message themselves:

> publish_actions 
>   Page Tab Words in the user message field must be
>   composed by the user and can’t be pre-filled by the app, even if the
>   user can edit or delete the words. See platform policy 2.3 here.

I have this object:

```
var wallPost = {
      message     : "Message text",
      link        : "https://url/reload/i<?php echo $id ?>",
      name        : "Header text",
      caption     : " ",                                     
      description : " ",
      picture     : "https://url/<?php echo $imgText ?>"
};
```

How can I change the function so that user can write the message and the app complies with Facebook rules?

Comment: Remove "Message Text" and let the user type in the text

Comment: Interesting idea, WizKid. The application posts automatically on user's wall when the photo is uploaded. Do you think it will start showing some form to enter the message, when I leave the value empty?

Comment: Either leave it empty or let the user type something in. Anything else is not allowed

Comment: Thank you WizKid, I left it empty. Let's see if it passes the review this time.